# Angular with CSS referenced from url parameter

Tags: angular

I have a simple form application in Angular 7. 
I've been asked to remove all styles from the app and put the styles into another location that. We would then pass the CSS URL as a parameter into our app and use that as the stylesheet.

My only issue with this, is that I want to have the current CSS as a default, in case parameter isn't passed into our app. How can I go about having the all the SCSS files (including components) compile into one CSS file so I can include that?

So would end up calling my URL https://localhost/?cssfile=my-css-file

I would see there is a URL parameter, so I'd then add a style link to my html

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href= "https://cssurl.com/cssfile=my-css-file.css" />
```

Comment: Are you wishing to keep styles-per-component using the default ViewEncapsulation, and then override these styles using external CSS?

Comment: Yes, I would need to have all the component styles as well as global styles put into one CSS file. I'm unsure how to do this though

Comment: You might be better off to set the ViewEncapsulation for the component to None and move your styles to a more global styles.scss file.  The surrogate ID attribute that is generated and placed in the elements in your component by the default ViewEncapsulation will make overriding these component styles difficult. Once all your styles are in a global file, it should be pretty easy to ensure the outputted css is contained within a single file, and override the styles with external assets.